# AntiForgery Exception: A required anti-forgery token was not supplied or was invalid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, antiforgerytoken

I have an MVC2 application. I am trying to implement AntiForgeryToken helper to prevent CSRF attacks.

I am implementing this using Steve Sanderson's blog: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/09/01/prevent-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-using-aspnet-mvcs-antiforgerytoken-helper/

When I implement this in a NEW MVC2 project it works. But the same code when I put it in my REAL application, it ALWAYS throws this exception: 
A required anti-forgery token was not supplied or was invalid.

Here is my Controller code:

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult SubmitUpdate()
{

    // Something goes here
    return View();
}
```

Code in View:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitUpdate", "Test"))
   {%>
   <%= Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
<% } %>
```

There is no difference in the two apps except that the real application uses ADFS for autentication. What am I missing? Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is the HTML that was generated?

Comment: Were you able to get a solution to this? I suddenly have the same issue on one server.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried deleting your cookies and trying again?

Comment: Yes I have. Delete the cache, delete all cookies, restart IIS, reboot my machine, etc.

Comment: This is the html it is generating.                             <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" value="O+c5O59wHPwKq3TO/VVHmVLbHbDBG1TTGbLKTuNZf+602IjkoRSnRX7GjMXnw5VnyNtfy4NjAWZaZ+uNv1ni4b6kP3ru1r51K7i4RgKV/TBxSY2ZsUDr6qGAC+vHjvG/ZE08UQ==" type="hidden"> <div> This is an index page <p> Name <input id="txtName" name="txtName" type="text"> </p> <p> <input value="Submit" type="submit"> </p> </div>

Answer (score 0):

Answer may lie in the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9896011/any-reason-not-to-trust-asp-net-antiforgerytoken/10201208#10201208) regarding a KB patch as well as ensuring the Machine key is static between all servers in your farm/cluster etc.