# What mistake could cause error: A required anti-forgery token was not supplied or was invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, antiforgerytoken

My question is very similar to this issue: [AntiForgery Exception: A required anti-forgery token was not supplied or was invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6792435/883931)
but I have the MVC3 and I using Razor installed.

controller has the

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
```

specified

in html is printed  `<input name="__RequestVerificationToken"...` using `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`

Also I observed, that **if I remove the Authorization cookie** in the browser, and controller method does not have `[Authorize]` **I don't have any problems with AntiForery**. Why?

Comment: is the `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` inside each form that you submit? or is it just floating out on the page somewhere?

Comment: Marc is correct.  Make sure the AntiForgeryToken helper is inside the Form tags.  Is this a standard request or an Ajax request?

Answer (score 0):

Check your cookies and make sure that you are seeing the requestVerificationToken cookie being set correctly. I have run into this before where the cookies for the site were all set to be SSL only and I was trying to run it over regular HTTP locally, so the cookie was never being accepted because it was being transmitted over unsecure channels.

For me, this meant changing a line in the web.config under system.web/httpCookies to requireSSL="false"... but if this isn't what you are seeing, I would still look at things that might be messing with your cookies in the system (e.g. session resets, manually clearing the cookies somewhere, etc.). If you have the validation attribute on the controller methods correctly, and are still getting this, it is likely due to something modifying or removing that cookie!

**Edit:** Also, if you have this on the controller instead of only on the POST methods, that would be why... This is only applicable to form POSTs to the server.

Here's a simple custom version that you CAN apply to the form that will automatically validate on ALL POST action methods:

```
/// <summary>
/// Custom Implementation of the Validate Anti Forgery Token Attribute.
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class CustomValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute _validator;

    /// <summary>
    /// The AcceptVerbsAttribute.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly AcceptVerbsAttribute _verbs;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="CustomValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="verbs">The verbs.</param>
    public CustomValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute(HttpVerbs verbs) : this(verbs, null)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="CustomValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="verbs">The verbs.</param>
    /// <param name="salt">The salt.</param>
    public CustomValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute(HttpVerbs verbs, string salt)
    {
        _verbs = new AcceptVerbsAttribute(verbs);
        _validator = new ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute
                         {
                             Salt = salt
                         };
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when authorization is required.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filterContext">The filter context.</param>
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var httpMethodOverride = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.GetHttpMethodOverride();

        var found = false;
        foreach (var verb in _verbs.Verbs)
        {
            if (verb.Equals(httpMethodOverride, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                found = true;
            }
        }

        if (found && !filterContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString().StartsWith("Json"))
        {
            _validator.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can just add the following to all of your controllers, or to your base controller if you override and inherit from one:

```
    [CustomValidateAntiForgeryToken(HttpVerbs.Post)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Anti forgery token is tied to the user identity. If you changing currently logged in user identity between generating and validating tokens then token will not be validated successfully. Also, that explains why everything is working for you in anonymous mode.